# iframe.scrollTo() doesn't work for Excel/PowerPoint documents on iPad

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iframe

I want to implement custom scrolling of iframe content for iPad. My solution is the following. I have iframe:

```
<div id="scroller" style="height: 300px; width: 100%; overflow: auto;">
    <iframe height="100%" id="iframe" width="100%" name="iframe" src="1.pdf" />
</div>
```

And in javascript code I use:

```
top.frames['iframe'].scrollTo(x,y);
```

It works perfectly for pdf documents, but not for Excel and Power Point documents.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to show a worddocument or excel directly/correctly inside an Iframe.
You could use Google documents viewer/drive to present the documents with.

Check http://docs.google.com/viewer and https://drive.google.com/

But if it's possible, I would stick with PDF's